# Is there a way to get the Current RPC User logged in?

Tags: corda

In a Corda Node is there a way to get the current RPC user logged in? As in which RPC user is actually making the request to the node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a flow, you can use:

```
stateMachine.context.origin.principal().name
```

This will return the name of the RPC user who started the flow as a string.